# Where do the special Environment Variable of HOSTNAME and HOSTTYPE stem from?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

### System

I have an Ubuntu-20.04 LTS Live Server image on a hardware device

### Requirements

I wish to set the hostname of a container exactly the same as that of the hostname of the hardware device

Upon pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> for autocompletion on `$HOS` one finds two envrionment variable in the terminal:

- `HOSTNAME`
- `HOSTTYPE`

The interesting thing about these variables is that they are neither found in:

- `printenv`
- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Making them unfortunately inaccessible to Docker Containers.

I am curious where do these variables stem from if they are not part of the standard files for environment variables?

Answer (score 3):

Both variables are builtin variables of the bash shell, the shell that in Ubuntu is used for interactive shells. This means that they exist in any running bash shell, and their value is set when `bash` loads.

Their purpose is to make that information immediately and always available for processes launched from the shell. Without this, processes that need that information would need to launch external tools to obtain that information. So the benefit of these builtin variables is convenience and performance for processes that need that information.

In contrast, the much slimmed down `dash` shell, used in Ubuntu for launching processes and symlinked to `sh`, does *not* provide these variable. Applications running under this shell need to rely on external tools to obtain that information.

`$HOSTNAME` contains the host name, and `$HOSTTYPE` identifies the system hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), these are set by bash. See [5.2 Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables):

> These variables are set or used by Bash, but other shells do not normally treat them specially.
>
> ...
>
> **HOSTNAME**
>
> The name of the current host.
>
> **HOSTTYPE**
>
> A string describing the machine Bash is running on.

Where does Bash get the information? I think it calls [`uname()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/oslib.c#n197) for these.